# JAX-RS Java EE 8: Gzip output JSON if some header is set

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly

I am working on a project on `Java EE 8`. I am using JAX-RS to build my APIs. Now, I would like to compress the output of all of my APIs (all APIs return JSON, by the way) if a header, like `gzip: 1` is found in request.

Is there any way to intercept all responses in `ContainerResponseFilter`, and then compress / GZIP the output JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a JAX- RS `WriterInterceptor` in order to alter the original outputstream.

Everything is explained here: https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-2rd-edition/en/part1/chapter12/reader_and_writer_interceptors.html

Hereunder the interesting part:

```
@Provider
public class GZIPEncoder implements WriterInterceptor {

   public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext ctx)
                    throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
      GZIPOutputStream os = new GZIPOutputStream(ctx.getOutputStream());
      ctx.getHeaders().putSingle("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
      ctx.setOutputStream(os);
      ctx.proceed();
      return;
   }
}
```

Now in order to share some information (flag to gzip or not) between the request and the response, you can use `InterceptorContext.set/getProperty` :

*"A property allows a JAX-RS filters and interceptors to exchange additional custom information not already provided by this interface.*"

So, first set a property when intercepting the request, and later use it inside your write interceptor (GZIPEncoder) to decide to compress or not.

Good luck

Comment: to add to TacheDeChoco.  --- you can double check to see if a header exists